# How to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I've loaded Ubuntu 14.04 onto a USB stick, and can get it to launch. However when I attempt to actually install Ubuntu it doesn't give me an option to dual boot. I only have the option to completely erase everything and install Ubuntu or do things manually, which I don't know how to do. I've heard it could be an issue with one operating system doing BIOS while the other is using UEFI, however windows is running BIOS and I think Ubuntu is as well. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One big question: have you partitioned your hard drive?
If you haven't I'd have a look at this:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/
(I know this is for Vista but it works on any modern Windoze version including 10)

Once you set up a separate partition for Ubuntu (and probably another much smaller space for Linux swap) then you can dual-boot by installing Ubuntu to that partition you set aside for it. Then when it asks for where to install grub, select /dev/sda (or whatever the name of your hard drive is)

Have no fear, the BIOS/UEFI thing is not an issue. I made my Ubuntu/Windoze system work on the first try!

Comment: You were right, it was a partition issue. I fixed it and formatted them correctly, now everything is downloaded right. Thanks!